# Cannot align center the image in jquery swiper slider

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4, swiper.js

On my bootstrap 4 website's homepage, i have a [jquery swiper slider](https://swiperjs.com/).

My problem is, that on mobile devices, the images are not aligned center. For example, if i vire the site on mobile, i dont see the full image, just the left side of it.

I tryed adding some css to the images, like background-position, but it didnt chenged anything.

Here is my demo site:
[Click here](https://uj.gras.hu/)

This is the slider:

```
    <section class="slider-01 mb-6">
   <div class="w-100 px-0">
      <div id="main-slider" class="swiper-container">
         <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-01 align-items-center d-flex bg-overlay-dark-20 header-position bg-holder" style="background-image: url(/images/swiper/3333.jpg);">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                     <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="banner-content">
                           <ul class="list-unstyled d-sm-flex" data-swiper-animation="fadeInDown" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>Kombi forma</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>Holdfény szín</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>6 cm vastag</li>
                           </ul>
                           <span class="animated d-block text-white mb-4 swiper_title" data-swiper-animation="fadeInUp" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">Weboldal tervezés és fejlesztés</span>
                           <h6 class="animated text-white mt-3 mb-3" data-swiper-animation="fadeInDown" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">Az egyedi és rugalmas webáruházak fejlesztése a világ egyik legnépszerűbb tartalomkezelő felületén történik.</h6>
                           <a class="custom_button mt-4" href="/terko-akcio" title="Tovább a részletekre" target="_self" data-swiper-animation="fadeInRight" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">Tovább a részletekre<i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right ml-3"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-slide slide-01 align-items-center d-flex bg-overlay-dark-20 header-position bg-holder" style="background-image: url(/images/swiper/2.jpg);">
               <div class="container">
                  <div class="row align-items-center">
                     <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
                        <div class="banner-content">
                           <ul class="list-unstyled d-sm-flex" data-swiper-animation="fadeInDown" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>Kombi forma</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>Holdfény szín</li>
                              <li><i class="fas fa-circle mr-1"></i>6 cm vastag</li>
                           </ul>
                           <span class="animated d-block text-white mb-4 swiper_title" data-swiper-animation="fadeInUp" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">Valósítsd meg ötleted a piacod legjobb webáruházával</span>
                           <h6 class="animated text-white mt-3 mb-3" data-swiper-animation="fadeInDown" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">A Magento a világ vezető nyílt forráskódú e-kereskedelmi platformja, amelyet vállalatok tízezrei használnak.</h6>
                           <a class="custom_button mt-4" href="/terko-akcio" title="Tovább a részletekre" target="_self" data-swiper-animation="fadeInRight" data-duration="2.0s" data-delay="0.5s">Tovább a részletekre<i class="fas fa-long-arrow-alt-right ml-3"></i></a>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
         <div class="swiper-button-prev" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
         <div class="swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>


/* Swiper */
.slider-01 .swiper-slide {
    height: 950px;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li {
    margin-right: 18px;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li a {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li a:hover {
    color: #84bc3c;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li a i {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #84bc3c;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.slider-01 .slide-01 h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    border-left: 3px solid #84bc3c;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li  {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.slider-01 .banner-content ul li  i {
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #84bc3c;
    margin-right: 8px;
}
.swiper_title {
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 65px;
    letter-spacing:0.2rem;
}
.slider-01 .slide-01 h6 {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--main_orange_color);
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.swiper-button-prev {
    left: 53px;
    background-image: inherit !important;
    outline: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.swiper-button-next {
    right: 53px;
    background-image: inherit !important;
    outline: none;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}
.swiper-button-next i {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.swiper-button-prev i {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

/* Swiper */

Comment: Post your code here so we can analyze your problem. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 0):

```
@media(max - width: 1199px) {
    .swiper - wrapper > .swiper - slide {
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
}
```

Put this responsive css

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didnt change nothing.

Comment: So i am not getting your point what exactly you need. because this css working on mobile device and image also center aligned.

Answer (score 0):

As you have given the image as a background image the only possible way that you can see complete image on responsive is to apply the below css:

```
.slider-01 .swiper-slide {
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

But this will not suit you as you have more content in the banner. So you can provide another image for responsiveness or you can use  inside the '.swiper-slide' instead of the background image and make it absolute position and give width and height 100%. So it will fit the entire area of the banner.